# doakn on vendor dashboard edit product in quick edit options find product status (draft or online)

Tags: wordpress, dokan

how to produce custom field edit (eg product status online or draft )in on doakn vendor dashboard quick edit panel. 
I want to product edit in quick edit popup by programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at or in Dokan-Lite>Templates>Products> tmpl-add-product-popup.php to see perhaps how you could do this? I would also recommend checking the same folder for new-product.php and new-product-single.php as they may contain relevant locations to mirror in order customize, modify, or add your code through your child-theme.

This doc was about the closest I could find in my research: [Unable to check if Custom Checkbox Product Meta, set in Dokan new-single-product.php is checked when looping through order items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027375/unable-to-check-if-custom-checkbox-product-meta-set-in-dokan-new-single-product)

And I found these in documentation, perhaps they will be helpful? 
https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/developer-documentation/functional-action-hooks/
https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/developer-documentation/seller-dashboard-action-hooks/

(I am in a similar quandary, likewise searching for how to modify fields of add product, however in my case would like them to reflect the fields on the edit product page. Or a redirect immediately after adding the product, however each product is unique per vendor? How to do this?!)

Do you also find that vendors do not input all of the necessary information?

If you get this figured out, do please let me know!